# Using Application Insights with multiple deployment slots

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I am beginning to implement Application Insights against an ASP.NET web app with multiple deployments; Prod, Staging, Dev, Dev2. Currently the production slot is sitting empty with deployments in staging, dev and dev2.

The application health tile is showing requests made to the home page of Prod but really I want to see the telemetry for staging, dev and dev2. Is it possible to use 1 Application Insights resource for all slots within my Web App or do I have to create a separate Application Insights for each slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I was enabling Application Insights through the portal for an already deployed application, which only seems to enable telemetry collections for what is deployed in the 'main' production slot. In my case this was the default 'This web app has been successfully created' blue landing screen. Despite my 3 other deployment slots having apps deployed, no data was collected for these.

In order to allow collection for all slots, return to Visual Studio and configure Application Insights through there. You can then redeploy the application to whichever deployment slot you wish and the OOTB telemetry collection will happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend your telemetry with [custom properties](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#properties) which will indicate your environment, and then slice and dice according to that property, using either [Metric Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-metrics-explorer/) or [Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/).

You can read more here: [Application Insights support for Multiple Environments, Stamps and App Versions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/), specifically the 'Multi Stamp Support'.

Comment: Would it be correct then to say that the out of the box telemetry is set to only function for the production slot? Handling logging for any other slots requires writing code in the application?

Comment: Azure Production slot? no. The OOB telemetry is sent from Staging as well, it is unaware of the slot it is sent from.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am experiencing as the production slot is the only one sending data despite deployments in 3 other slots.

Comment: I guess we're not talking about the same thing. I was talking about Azure deployment slots, which has only two - Production & Staging.

Comment: I'm talking about Web Apps where you can have up to 5 deployment slots depending on the chosen App Service plan.

I definitely take you point about custom properties to differentiate between which slots the logs are coming from but not yet at that point.

Comment: Ahh OK. Read this: [Application Insights support for Multiple Environments, Stamps and App Versions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/), specifically the 'Multi Stamp Support' which provides the same solution that I've suggested.

Comment: have you enabled sending data to App Insights on the staging slot? That seems to be the issue